# How to project LINQ-to-SQL query into custom object with a GroupBy and OrderBy

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to convert this query so that it will output to a custom DTO type object. I want to get only pages with the highest revision number for the `int[]` that I pass in.

```
return from page in db.Pages
               where intItemIdArray.Contains(page.pageId)
               group page by page.pageId into g
               orderby g.Max(x => x.pageId)
               select g.OrderByDescending(t => t.revision).First();
```

But when I try to replace

```
select g.OrderByDescending(t => t.revision).First();
```

With something like

```
select (new JPage {pageid = g.pageId, title = g.title, etc})
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.revision)
    .First();
```

It doesn't work, can anyone help me out?

---

This is what I have gone with currently, which I don't like, but it is working perfectly, and I don't need to optimize beyond this currently.

It would be great if someone could improve this.

```
var pages = from page in db.Pages
               where intItemIdArray.Contains(page.pageId)
               group page by page.pageId into g
               orderby g.Max(x => x.pageId)
               select g.OrderByDescending(t => t.revision).First();

        return pages.Select(x => new JPage() { 
            pageId = x.pageId,
            pageKey = x.pageKey,
            title = x.title,
            body = x.body,
            isFolder = x.isFolder.ToString(),
            leftNode = x.leftNode,
            rightNode = x.rightNode,
            revision = x.revision,
            sort = x.sort,
            createdBy = x.createdBy.ToString(),
            createdDate = Utility.DateTimeToUnixTimeStamp(x.createdDate).ToString(),
            modifiedDate = Utility.DateTimeToUnixTimeStamp(x.modifiedDate).ToString(),
            pageVariationId = x.pagesVariationId,
            parentId = x.parentId
        })
        .AsQueryable();
```

Comment: You know you are missing a parenthesis in there right ? `etc}).`

Comment: Hey, thanks for noting, yes if I had missed that in the real thing I would catch that. Just being a bit stupid about these linq queries!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that you order *before* you select; i.e. instead of

```
select (new JPage {pageid = g.pageId, title = g.title, etc}
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.revision).First();
```

you should try

```
.OrderByDescending(t => t.revision)
    .Select(new JPage {pageid = g.pageId, title = g.title, etc})
    .First();
```

You can't order by 'revision' if it doesn't exist in the result of the previous 'select'

Comment: When I try to assign into the projected object, pageid = g.page id, it doesn't let me because at that point g is a collection, and so doesn't hold the parameters. Could you submit the full version of your solution, sorry if I am being stupid! I'm still trying to get it to work now!

Answer (score 0):

This should be a slight improvement

```
var pages = from page in db.Pages
               where intItemIdArray.Contains(page.pageId)
               group page by page.pageId into g
               select g.First(a => a.revision == g.Max(b => b.revision));
```